# c# events on database CRUD

Tags: c#, events, sharepoint, event-handling, inotifypropertychanged

Please notice: SharePoint is just an example!

If you guys are familiar with SharePoint, in there you can create custom event receivers. By that I mean that you can trigger specific actions when things happens like:

- before adding an item
- before modifying and item
- before deleting and item
- after adding an item
- after modifying and item
- after deleting and item
- etc.

Now this doesn't have anything to do with SharePoint is just a custom solution.

My question is: assuming I have a database (but this can be for example for adding/modifying files in folder, etc) how can I create custom events that will listen to these actions and trigger certain actions when something occurs?

Answer (score 0):

- When you want something similar like event receivers for databases, you are actually looking for 'triggers'. I can not explain all of it in this window but i'm sure you know your way to find information
- For a file system to add event receivers, it depends on which language you are using. For example, using c# you can use the FileSystemWatcher class (in System.IO). It will, as the name says, watch you files or folders and fire events (onDelete, onChange, etc...)

Comment: My question is about a generic way of handling this kind of events ... something like I declare an interface that exposes 2 functionalities: BeforeAdding and AfterAdding. Now this interface can be implemented to add items to a database, files to a folder, azure rows into a table, etc, etc, etc. All I need is to trigger 2 events regardless to where the data is stored ...